# How to add handler to internal NLog exceptions?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

In case of loss of internet connectivity, my desktop application with network logger set to logstash on my server (json over HTTP) starts to fail sending logs. Depending on configuration of NLog, it will either throw exception on each log POST request, either it will just output them to console.

Is there a way to subscribe to those exceptions or error information in NLog in a way I could control if my application should still try sending those logs?

Comment: Think you are waiting for this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3350

Comment: Until then you can listen to `NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogWriter` and scan the WriteLine-events for interesting sub-strings.

Comment: Oh, thanks, thought I absolutely missed something in docs. Custom LogWriter should get me started.